# Jquery input validate

Tags: jquery, forms, input

```
<input name="e-1" id="e-1" type="text" value=""/>
<input name="e-2" id="e-2" type="text" value=""/>
```

I need a Jquery code, which will immediately add the Input values here

```
<div id="x"></div>
```

My code isn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#e-1').bind('blur keyup',function() {
    if($('input#e-1').val()) {
      $('#x').html($('input#e-1').val());  
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow... that's not a question. Try rephrasing the comment into a question - your not a fan of jeopardy, are you?

Comment: Okay, so - how do I change my code to make it work?

Comment: What do you want it to do, what current happens (include detail on any error messages) and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that when you delete input (ie with `backspace` or by selecting all and then pressing `DEL`) the last character will stay visible in the div then thats because you have `if($('input#e-1').val())` test there, just delete it and it should work, ie

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#e-1').bind('blur keyup',function() {
      $('#x').html($('input#e-1').val());  
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am selecting only `e-1` the `input` and bind only the `keyup`. Also I am using the `append()` function to append all the inputs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#e-1').bind('keyup',function() {
    if($('#e-1').val()) {
      $('#x').append( ', ' + $('#e-1').val() );  
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for example, but I need another code :)

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#e-1").keyup(function(){
          if($('input#e-1').val()) {
             $('#x').html($('input#e-1').val());  
          }
      });
 });
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7tDQ7/)